# Resharper space between equals

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

is possible to add spaces between equals? Like this [image](http://others.sionzee.cz/looks.JPG).

Spaces are on the left side of '='.

Plain Text:

```
string foo             = "";
string boo             = "";

string <big space>     = "";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ReSharper doesn't have this feature, but it exists in [Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace), it's called `Align Assignments`:

> **Align Assignments**
>
> Aligns assignment statements by typing Ctrl+Alt+]. For example, typing
> Ctrl-Alt-] when the following is selected:
>
> [image]
>
> Transforms it into this:
>
> [image]
>
> Note! This may conflict with your formatting settings. E.g. in C# you will need to disable: Tools->Options->Text
> Editor->C#->Formatting->Spacing->"Ignore spaces in declaration
> statements"

However, since ReSharper has its own formatting rules, it might reformat your alignments. You could either disable ReSharper's formatting, or just press Ctrl-Z to undo, if it messes up your code.

You can also achieve this manually by using [Box Selection (also called Vertical Selection)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2013/07/15/visual-studio-2013-using-box-selection-and-zero-length-box-selection.aspx).

Hope this helps!